# Kubernetes Cluster with Ingress - Remote IP

Tags: ibm-cloud

We are hosting our cluster at IBM Bluemix and use the out of the box setup, nothing really modified.
We have a few ingress controllers that handle routing to our internal microservices ( Around 12 ) of them.

We use all the standard ALB's, Ingress etc from Bluemix

Inside our microservices we want to be able to log the IP number some specific calls come from for audit pruposes etc, and all the Microservices are reciving the headers x-real-ip x-forwarded-for but they have an incorrect IP number.. i think its the loadbalancers or something similar that is causing the incorrect IP

How do i solve this ?

Comment: It depends on which Ingress Controller you are asking. Not all of them have the same config.

Comment: How can i check this ? 
`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-api-entrypoint
  annotations:
    ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path
`

Comment: usually when there are several ingress controllers in the cluster, you select one through annotations, but unfortunately I don't know how to get this info from bluemix IC.